# How do I host HTML files on cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

the answer to this question must be so trivial because I can't find anything that spells it out for me.
I'm trying to set up a database on cloudant but I keep hearing that to abide the same origin policy the html files will need to be hosted in the same location.
How do I get my html files onto my cloudant domain?

I feel pretty stupid that I haven't been able to figure this out for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As attachments.

Upload your files as attachments and then access them by going to `https://you.cloudant.com/dbname/documentid/name_of_file.html`.

Tools like [erica](https://github.com/benoitc/erica) ([a bigger list of options here](https://cloudant.com/blog/app-management/)) will do that for you. With them, you just need to put all your HTML, CSS and JS files in a folder and the tool will save them all as attachments of a **Design Document**, then that bundle will become your Couchapp.

(After that you just have to mix some ajax calls to `_views` and pure docs with links to `_list` and `_show` functions -- if you want -- and you'll be a complete couchapper).

Answer (score 3):

You can host static sites on Cloudant similarly to CouchDB. Your best "Getting Started" resource is probably [CouchApp.org](http://couchapp.org/page/index) which explains the mechanism and provides links to tooling which will help you bundle the assets together.

It's also worth mentioning that Cloudant [now supports CORS](https://cloudant.com/blog/cors-and-faceted-search-coming-soon-to-a-cloudant-cluster-near-you/) so an externally hosted site is possible as well.